# Book on interpreting plots in regression analysis

Tags: regression, data-visualization, spss, references

I am taking a regression course that is mainly theoretical. But we are given scatter plots and residual plots, and we are supposed to be able to describe the relationships and interpret them.  I find interpretation part difficult sometimes. Is there a good book that has exercises using SPSS output that I can use to help me interpret regression plots?

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

- Cook, R. D. (1999). *[Regression Graphics: Ideas for Studying Regressions through Graphics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471193658)*.

It isn't SPSS-based as far as I know (and for the record I haven't read it), but the substance of the plots that come with regression output should be sufficiently similar from software to software that it shouldn't matter.

---

You can also try reading through some of the threads on CV that are categorized under the tags [regression](/questions/tagged/regression) and [data-visualization](/questions/tagged/data-visualization) (e.g., [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regression+data-visualization?sort=votes&pageSize=30)), or even under [spss](/questions/tagged/spss), [residuals](/questions/tagged/residuals), or [interpretation](/questions/tagged/interpretation).

Finally, you should feel free to come back here with specific questions you have.  Just post a plot you are having trouble with and ask how to interpret it.  If CV won't let you post an image because your reputation is too low, you can upload it to [imgur.com](https://imgur.com/) and include a link to it in your question.  Someone will add the figure for you.  If the plot is for a homework problem, you should add the `[self-study]` tag and explain what you have tried already, but you don't need to add the `[self-study]` tag otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot.In statistics I have a somewhat good theoretical knowledge.But when it comes to interpreting I always make mistakes

Comment: You're welcome, @clarkson. You should always feel free to come back w/ specific questions. There are a number of questions about interpreting plots already on CV; we can point you to those as well.

Comment: Alas, the book has no reference to SPSS nor any other software. It is also B&W.